# How to get Gene ontology (GO) terms per probe

Tags: r, ontology, bioconductor

I am new to R/BioC. I am trying to do GO-based clustering of genes. The input needs to be gene name and GO terms in each row. 
Example:

```
AP4B1 GO:0005215 GO:0005488 GO:0005515 GO:0005625 GO:0005802 GO:0005905
BCAS2 GO:0005515 GO:0005634 GO:0005681 GO:0008380 GO:0031202
```

I tried using annotate in bioconductor:

```
library("rat2302.db") 
library(annotate)
testid<-c("1367462_at","1380262_at", "1392516_a_at", "1396521_at")
goid1 <- rat2302GO[testid]
```

But I get only each GO term in seperate row:

```
toTable(goid1)

probe_id      go_id Evidence Ontology
1  1367462_at GO:0008152      IEA       BP
2  1367462_at GO:0008152      ISO       BP
3  1367462_at GO:0006508      IMP       BP
4  1367462_at GO:0005886      IEA       CC
5  1367462_at GO:0005737      IEA       CC
6  1380262_at GO:0005575       ND       CC
7  1380262_at GO:0005634      IEA       CC
8  1380262_at GO:0005737      IEA       CC
9  1367462_at GO:0005509      IEA       MF
10 1367462_at GO:0005509      TAS       MF
11 1367462_at GO:0004198      IDA       MF
12 1367462_at GO:0004198      IEA       MF
13 1367462_at GO:0004198      ISO       MF
14 1367462_at GO:0046982      IPI       MF
15 1380262_at GO:0000166      IEA       MF
```

Maybe there is an easier way to get all GO terms per gene. Unfortunately, I could not find it.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks
R

Comment: I suggest asking on the [Bioconductor](http://bioconductor.org/help/mailing-list/) mailing list instead.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, from your example of the input, it is not clear how exactly you want to format your input. Is what you have presented a `data.frame`? Or is it two character vectors where the first element is the gene name? Or do you want a .txt file formatted as your example?

I guess that the easiest thing to do is simply `split` by the `probe_id`, as follows

```
tab <- toTable(goid1)
split(tab$go_id, tab$probe_id)
```

which gives the output

```
$`1367462_at`
[1] "GO:0006508" "GO:0005886" "GO:0005737" "GO:0070062" "GO:0005509" "GO:0004198" "GO:0046982"
[8] "GO:0005509" "GO:0004198"

$`1380262_at`
[1] "GO:0005575" "GO:0005634" "GO:0005737" "GO:0015459" "GO:0004674" "GO:0005524" "GO:0015459"
[8] "GO:0015459"

$`1396521_at`
[1] "GO:0008289"
```

In any case. This is list of vectors of GO-terms for each gene/probeset as you want. It should be fairly easy to manipulate this into what you want.

Answer (score 0):

ncbi provides a file named gene2go, which may be the one you want